# How to close typesafe activator?

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I ran the .bat file for typesafe activator, and it works fine. However, I can't figure out how to close it! It runs in at least 2 different processes, and closing the cmd from the bat file only closes one of those! Plus, it doesn't delete the PID file, so I have to delete that or it will think that I am running it while its already running!
How do you exit out of it?

Comment: Did you type `activator start` or `activator run`?

Comment: No, I ran the bat file, now how do I close both processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just run the batch file, you'll get the UI version, which runs in a browser. If you close its browser tab or window, the console application will shutdown itself after some seconds -- at least the 1.3.x version behaves so.

Comment: Yeah, the only issue is that this sometimes doesn't work. When it doesn't, I just close the cmd window and delete the RUNNING_PID file. Thanks!